# Short HDMI cable - 10 or 20 cm for Raspberry PI

Tags: hdmi, cable

I need a short HDMI cable (Male-Male) to connect a Raspberry PI 3B+ to a [HDMI Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GPU84A6) (the monitor is shared between the Raspberry and a PC). It should have 10 cm or maximum 20 cm and I have difficulties finding such thing. When searching for it, I land on pages for products like micro HDMI cables, HDMI to VGA adapter cables or even HDMI extension cords.
There is a good store in the area where I live specialized only in cables for electronics and the shortest HDMI cable they have is 50 cm.

I guess I'm not the only one who has to share a monitor between a PC and a micro computer like Raspberry PI so a good answer to this question might be quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know what country you're in so I can't be sure of this suggestion, these offerings are available on UK Amazon ([1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/0-15m-HDMI-Short-Patch-Cable-Gold/dp/B01CT2FP24/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1540285589&sr=8-7&keywords=short%20hdmi%20cable%200.1m)) ([2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SHORT-15cm-HDMI-CABLE-GOLD-x/dp/B00KX50VB0/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1540285589&sr=8-13&keywords=short%20hdmi%20cable%200.1m)).

I found these with a search for "Short HDMI Cable 0.1m". There were a lot of offerings at 0.25m, but these were the only ones I could see shorter than that.